# How to get feedback from an action in Xcode

Tags: ipad

I'm new to using Xcode to program apps for the iPad. As expected, some of my first attempts at activating actions from a button don't work. What I'd like to do (as I do in scripting programs) is get some feedback from the action i.e., a feedback message to tell me the action received the activation message. Similarly, I'd like the action to give me feedback on the values of the variables and properties it is using.

How can I arrange this in the coding?
Grateful for any help here :)

Peter Small

Answer (score 0):

In the button click event code you can write NSLog(@"Button was pressed");
That would give message in the console,through which you can get idea that your method was called.Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your very quick response Sarah. Much appreciated.

Comment: Yes. Your solution works fine and gives me a way of getting feedback from inside my action. Just what I was looking for. Thanks Sarah.

Comment: I still have the problem though of getting feedback on what the values of my properties are within the action. I tried NSLog(userOutput.text); but this didn't work.

Comment: u need to use NSLog(@"userOutput.text value is : %@",userOutput.text); Also once you get solution you should tick the check mark given next to the answer to specify that you get the solution.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Log the properties using `NSLog(@"Button pressed:%@", userOutput.text);`